Time complexity for finding min/max in an array of strings
Suppose I have an array/list that consists of string elements like:
arr=["abcd","abdd","abba", "abca"] and I want to find the min and max element here (i.e. abba and abdd), what will be the time complexity of running a min(arr)/max(arr) function here.
I know for numerical elements we can do it O(n) as there's just 1 comparison at every step.
But for when we compare 2 strings we have to iterate its characters to compare. So does that make it
somewhere in the order of O(n^2)??

"I know for numerical elements we can do it O(n)" - Really? Ints can be arbitrarily long, just like strings...

What do you mean with "n"?

When comparing strings lexicographically (this is usually done when finding the smallest and largest strings in a string), the time difficulty is different from comparing numbers. ^2).
Now let's look at it in detail:
Compare two strings: If the strings have different characters in the first position, just one comparison is enough to determine which came first. If they have the same character, the comparison moves to the next character. At worst, you have to compare each character until you find a difference or reach the end of a string. The worst thing is when the strings are equal or one string comes before another string. Therefore, this requires n comparisons; where n is the number of strings in the array.
But in general long string is similar and different and comparison is faster. So although the maximum time complexity is O(n*m) it is usually faster in practice.
m is the max length of string in 0(n*m).

What is your m?

m is the maximum length of the strings.

Please edit your answer to include this clarification
